# JavaScript matching unicode letters

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the best way to match any letter from any language? That's what I'm doing:

```
  let str1 = "aabb";
  console.log( str1.replace( /\w/gu, "$&|") ); //→ a|a|b|b|
  let str2 = "aābḇ";
  console.log( str2.replace( /\w/gu, "$&|") ); //→ a|Äb|á¸‡
```

I want to have something like `sed` and `grep`:

```
$ echo aābḇ | sed 's/\w/&|/g'
a|ā|b|ḇ|

$ echo "ʔ.ā^ḫ&" | grep -o '\w'
ʔ
ā
ḫ
```

The same question about unicode `\b`.

Comment: Take a look at Technical Committee 39, [this page](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes) specifically.

Comment: @revo I'm a newbie, so I can't figure out if there is a simple solution (without using XRegExp). I've tried to use `/\p{L}/gu`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for: `console.log( str2.replace( /[^\s.,:;]/gu, "$&|") ); //→ a|ā|b|ḇ

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks! That's approximately what I'm doing now, but it's very inconvenient, since with real data the list of `\W` symbols is very large.

Comment: I try again:  console.log( str2.replace( /[a-z\u00C0-\u017F]/gu, "$&|") ); I'm using this list of Unicode characters https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Comment: @enxaneta I doesn't work on either chromium or firefox with any non-English characters.